# Problems with file inclusion for variadic class

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I have a `variadic template class` and I'm trying to include my namespace which is in another file so that I can use a few functions from it in the class.

However, the file including the namespace also includes a using statement related to the class as I need the variadic class for a few functions in that namespace as well.

I have many errors trying to do this and was wondering if there is a way to achieve my goal...

Here is what I mean:

```
#include "VariadicClass.hpp"
#include <stdint.h>
using VariadicClass3 = VariadicClass<3, int>

namespace mynamespace {
   int function1(VariadicClass3 param){return 1;}
   int function2(){return 0;}
}

////////////////////////////////////////////
#include "MyNamespace.hpp"
#include <stdint.h>
template<std::size_t T_size, typename T>
class VariadicClass3 {
    public:
        //...
        void function1(){
            auto some_var = mynamespace::function2();
        }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have couple of typos in your posted code. Ignoring that for the time being, you can use forward declaration as shown below to remove the cyclic dependency:

MyNamespace.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>

// Forward declare the class.
template<std::size_t T_size, typename T> class VariadicClass;

using VariadicClass3 = VariadicClass<3, int>;

namespace mynamespace {

   // Use the class only in reference in declaration.
   // If the implementation of the function needs to 
   // access to members of VariadicClass3, it needs to be
   // in a .cpp file where VariadicClass.hpp can be #include'd.
   int function1(VariadicClass3 const& param){return 0;}

   int function2(){return 1;}
}
```

VariadicClass.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include "MyNamespace.hpp"

template<std::size_t T_size, typename T>
class VariadicClass {
   public:
      //...
      void function1(){
         auto some_var = mynamespace::function2();
      }
};
```